# STL Container default Initialization

Tags: c++, stl

Hello 
I have following `struct`

```
struct node {
   std::string word
   std::vector<struct node *> child;
}
```

When I create the new node, I have no way to initialize `child vector`.
What I essentially want is to check any element using `operator[]` is there is valid value.
I want to do following

```
if ( nodeptr->child[5] )  {
}
```

But Code crashes at if loop.

Is there other way to handle this.

Comment: In C++, `struct` in `struct node *` is not needed. `node*` is enough!

Comment: Are the vectors meant to be of any specific size at runtime? Is it fine to do `child[5]` and `child[50]`? Or does the vector grow and you only need to know if it has grown beyond one point (i.e. the pointer at position N is not 0, if it exists at all)?

Comment: You should state what the problem that you want to resolve is, rather than your approach to a solution (or additionally to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you would have to provide a constructor for you struct.

```
struct node {
   node() : word(), child(10, NULL) {}
   std::string word
   std::vector<struct node *> child;
}
```

This will initialize the vector with 10 `NULL`-pointers. You can then check if an index is `NULL` (meaning it does not contain data), or not (it does contain data).

Comment: But I have not yet inserted any elements in the child vector. and I want to check if there any valid element in the specified index.

Comment: In that case you're going to have to do more work. Change your check to: `if( child.size() >= 6 && child[ 5 ] )`

Comment: thanks , one more question will it handle querying 11th or bigger index element.

Comment: @Avinash: No it won't. If you need that functionality, you would have to use a `std::map`.

Comment: @Avinash, @Space_COwBOy: perhaps it's less ambiguous to say that `child[10]` can be valid if there's been a `resize(11)` (or more) or `push_back(extra_value)` beforehand, whereas `std::map::operator[]` will actually create a missing element with whatever key you try to access automatically.

Answer (score 4):

The question is not clear on what your actual problem is, that is whether you need the vector go have a given size after construction or whether you just want to check if a fifth element was inserted.

In the first case, the size of the vector is an invariant of the node class, you should enforce the invariant during the construction. Add a constructor to `node` (as others have suggested before):

```
struct node {
   static const int NUM_CHILDREN = 10;
   std::string word;
   std::vector<node*> child;

   node() : word(), child( NUM_CHILDREN ) {}
};
```

If, on the other hand, the size of the vector is not an invariant, and you want to check whether the fifth element was inserted and whether it is non null, then change the if condition:

```
if ( nodeptr->child.size() > 5 && nodeptr->child[5] ) {
```

That condition will verify first that the vector has grown enough (to access the element at position 5, the size must be 6 or above), and then whether the element at position 5 is not null. Note that `&&` will short circuit, so if the first condition is not met, the second condition is not tested.

Comment: I want a container in which I should be able to check if the valid element exists at a specified index and I should be able to insert a new pointers at any index, I tried using stl vector.

Comment: @Avinash: As David already told you, this information should have been part of your question.

Comment: @Avinash, you cannot do that, std::vector is a dynamically sized container, i.e. it grows as you need. At the start it will be empty, when you add one item (say using the `push_back()` method), it will grow by one and you can access that index via `[0]` etc. To do what you are trying to do, you need to know before hand how many elements will be in it, say 100, then initialize the vector with 100 NULLs. Then you can access any index up to 100, if you need 100 or above, then you need to `resize()` the vector again. What you are trying to do sounds more like it needs a map, with index as the key.

Answer (score 3):

Vector has a constructor which takes a count and a value.

```
vector(
   size_type _Count,
   const Type& _Val
);
```

Use that. Define a constructor for node:

node::node()
: child( 10, NULL )
{
}